# Dockerize next.js 13 docker-compose.yml

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose

I'm building a next.js 13 app, I want to dockerize it.

My docker file Dockerfile is working but now I want to use docker-compose.yml file to use my dockerfile.

I tried old versions new versions light versions.

But I'm keep getting this error, I read different forums and blog post and also asked ai to help me out but i'm keep getting the same error over and over again:

```
docker-next-app-1  | 
docker-next-app-1  | > my-app@0.1.0 start
docker-next-app-1  | > next start
docker-next-app-1  | 
docker-next-app-1  | 
docker-next-app-1  | - ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
docker-next-app-1  | [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/.next/BUILD_ID'] {
docker-next-app-1  |   type: 'Error',
docker-next-app-1  |   errno: -2,
docker-next-app-1  |   code: 'ENOENT',
docker-next-app-1  |   syscall: 'open',
docker-next-app-1  |   path: '/app/.next/BUILD_ID'
docker-next-app-1  | }
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./app/my-app/package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3.8'

#ssl not working local only on server

services:

  next-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: C:\Users\user\WorkSpace\Test\Docker\app\my-app\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\WorkSpace\Test\Docker\app\my-app:/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
```

The command I use is: docker compose up --build

--build flag because of the first time build.

I tried different versions of node and looked at different forums tried different combinations but keep getting different errors.

just want to keep it so simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're mounting the entire `/app` directory via `volumes`, when the container starts, essentially everything you've done in the dockerfile is thrown away and the container sees what is in `C:\Users\MyUser\WorkSpace\Test\Docker\app\my-app` instead.

If you want to mount the entire folder, you'll need to additionally run `npm run build` *after* starting the container.

Comment: You are totally right... still learning but sometimes its so confusing...

Comment: Deleting the `volumes:` block is probably a better approach.  Since the (built) code is in your image already, you don't need a separate volume mount for it.